# How to show error by clicking send button in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

I really tried a lot to get out of it,i search various sites but every where they show validations on touch or they just hide button untill form is valid.How can i how validations just by clicking button,this is what i tried so far....................

My Template,

```
      <form id="login-form" name="login-form" class="nobottommargin" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" novalidate>
       <div class="col_full"> 
        <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['email']" id="login-form-username" name="login-form-username" value="" placeholder="username" class="form-control not-dark formcontrolheight" required>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="form.controls['email'].touched && form.submitted">

        <strong>Email is required</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="col_full">
     <input type="password" [formControl]="form.controls['phone']" id="login-form-password" name="login-form-password" value="" placeholder="password" class="form-control not-dark formcontrolheight" required>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="form.controls['phone'].touched && form.submitted" >

        <strong>Password is required</strong>

  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="col_full nobottommargin">
     <button class="col-xs-12 button button-mini loginbuttoncss  nomargin" id="login-form-submit" name="login-form-submit" value="login">Login</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </form>
```

but this is not going to work,can someone suggest the best practise to get the form to onsubmit function in mycase.....

Answer (score 1):

Angular runs validation on each value change. What you can do is to just hide the errors until you want them to be shown.

```
<div *ngIf="form.controls['email'].touched && form.submitted">
```

`form.submitted` was added recently. You need to use the latest Angular2 and forms module versions.

Comment: Gunter,should i need to include anything in my ts or form.submitted is enough?

Comment: You shouldn't need anything else.

Comment: Gunter,it is not working i think i am wrong somewhere,edited my code can you check it

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: As mentioned you need the latest version - RC.5

Comment: You can also set a property yourself when you submit and use `isSubmitted` instead of `form.submitted` to check your `isSubmitted` property instead if you don't want to update.

Comment: so i need to replace my template with isSubmitted?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "replace my template". If you maintain the submitted state yourself in a property, then you use this property (with whatever name you choise) in the `*ngIf` expression instead of `form.submitted`

Comment: sorry Gunter,i did not understood.Can you please explain

Comment: i just kept "form.submitted" in my template and nothing in my ts but it is not working and samething i done with isSubmitted also but not working

Comment: `form.submitted` is not supported in RC.2. No point in trying without updating. You need to create a property `isSubmitted` in your component and set the state yourself when the form is submitted for `&& isSubmitted` to work.

Comment: i had done like this...  onSubmit(form: any) {
        this.isSubmitted == true;
        if(form.email == '' && form.phone == ''){
            return
        }

Comment: Then `<div *ngIf="form.controls['email'].touched && isSubmitted">` should show the error only after `onSubmit()` was called